# How to loop through multiple rows in a data frame

Tags: r, oracle11g, dplyr, roracle

I have a very big `data.frame` with over 500,000 rows in it.

Now I need to retrieve data for each row from my database(Oracle 11g).
Trick is I don't know how to run hundreds of thousands queries efficiently.

I have been trying to use `dplyr` for this but I couldn't find documentation on how to do it. I should note that I only have read access to my database.

My code:

```
DeliveredIds$ID <- c(1:500000)

sql_select(db_conn,
       select = c("ID", "CATEGORY"),
       from = "DELIVERIES",
       where = list(ID %in% DeliveredIds$ID, #the 500K IDs that I need to query data for
                    ASOF = as.Date("2017-01-31"))
       )
```

Initially  I tried to do this through `ROracle` but I got error saying that I'm trying to query too many items at once(I don't have this code any more).

So to reiterate my question is how to loop through a data.frame by not one but multiple rows?

### Note

I am totaly open to other solutions but at this point the only thing that I can think of is write a loop that queries couple hundred rows at a time and updates the database on the go(not very efficient, but I doubt I have other options).

Comment: You want an `inner join` - this is much better than a `where` clause with 500k items or 500k individual queries. I don't have experience with `dplyr::sql_join` but I doubt you can use it to join a db table with an R data frame. If your `DeliveredIds` can be built in SQL (even with `dplyr`'s help), then joining on the DB side will be efficient

Comment: The SQL query you want is `select ID, category FROM deliveries inner join DeliveredIds on DelivereIds.id = deliveries.id where ASOF = to_date('2017-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`. Your other option - if memory permits - is to bring the `deliveries` table (for your `ASOF` date) into R and do the join on the R side.

Comment: The inefficient and annoying option would be to use the `in` clause 1000 rows at a time (the limit for an Oracle `in` clause).